# Can I cover rebar sticking vertically out of the ground with something that would permit me to pour concrete over top of it?

Tags: concrete, corrosion, ground, rebar

First off, this project is free from review from inspectors; i.e. none of this has to be to code.

I want to pour a concrete column.  The column isn't structural - it's like a column you may find at the end of a driveway.  In my mind, I think I would be better off "anchoring" it so it doesn't slowly migrate downhill.  Again, there is no appreciably slope, this is hypothetical (there really isn't a slope, I'm just thinking of reasons why things may move - the more likely cause it getting hit by a bumper, really).

I see post after post talk about the "don't"'s of hammering rebar into the ground and then pouring concrete around it.  I understand that the rebar will give moisture a way into your concrete.  It will eventually rust and destroy the integrity of your concrete.

The deal is I have six rebar sticking out of the ground right where I want to build a form and pour a column of concrete.  Rather than just cut the existing rebar off at the surface, I'd like to utilize them as "anchors" by putting something non-corrosive over top of them and taking advantage of the "staying power" they have to offer.

Can I cover them up with something?  Sort of like a rebar condom.  Does such a thing exist?  Can I use aluminum foil or a plastic tube to protect the concrete from the corrosive rebar?

Comment: Paint will help some, and it's cheap and easy. "Cold galvanize" zinc paint even better.

Comment: From what I have seen in other posts, aluminum and concrete do NOT play well together. So plastic or zinc or possibly some other metal, but not aluminum.

Comment: There is an article dealing with just that issue at https://www.structuremag.org/?p=10047 which suggests specific methods for galvanizing, epoxy coating or enameling. There are also spray epoxy paints, e.g. https://news.thomasnet.com/fullstory/epoxy-coating-protects-rebar-from-rust-and-corrosion-30742 , though I don't know if they're as effective as fusion-bonded epoxy.

Comment: the re-bar is embeedded in what? earth? concrete? rock?

Comment: It's in earth.  All other comments very helpful!  Sounds like I do have options.

Comment: Great references, @DrMoishePippik  You're either a master googler or a structural engineer that knows your stuff! :)